# How can you use JSON data to generate menu components dynamically using map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

Im trying to dynamically create a set of menuitems, using data pulled from json. I am currently trying to do this by mapping values with props, but i am failing somewhere.

Here is the code i use to attempt to do this:

```
Const Generate = () => {
  {data.items.map(({id, url, title}) => (
     <MenuItem key={id}> 
      <Link to={url}> {title} </Link> 
     </MenuItem>
))
console.log('lol')}
}
```

and here is the component that is trying to utlize this. Commented out is out it looks and works well whilst hardcoded.

```
const Navigation = ({}) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Layout>
    <Sider
      breakpoint="xs"
      collapsedWidth="0"
      onBreakpoint={broken => {
      }}
      onCollapse={(collapsed, type) => {
      }}
    >
      <div className="logo">
          <h1 style={{ color: 'white', paddingLeft: 20, paddingTop: 26}}>
              {Generate}
          </h1>
      </div>
      <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}>
        {Generate()}
        {/* <Menu.Item key="1">
        <Link to="/" > Hjem </Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="2">
        <Link to="/skjema"> Mine Skjema </Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="3">
        <Link to="/pasient"> Mine Pasienter </Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="4">
            Søk
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="5">
            Filtrer
        </Menu.Item>   */}
      </Menu>
    </Sider>

    <Layout>
      <Header className="site-layout-sub-header-background" style={{ padding: 0 }} />
      <Content style={{ margin: '24px 16px 0' }}>
        <div className="content">
          <Switch>
            <Route  exact path={"/"} component={Dashboard} />
            <Route  exact path="/Skjema" component={MineSkjema} />
            <Route  exact path="/Pasient" component={MinePasienter} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Content>
      <Footer />
    </Layout>
  </Layout>
  </React.Fragment>
)

export default withRouter(Navigation);
```

for reference, here is the json structure:

```
const data =
  {
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "url": "/",
      "title": "Hjem"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "url": "/Skjema",
      "title": "Mine Skjema"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,  
      "url": "/Pasient",
      "title": "Hjem"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "url": "/Search",
      "title": "Søk"
    }
  ]
  }
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Do you see your "lol" console printed? I would suggest trying to make sure that you data is accessible to the `Generate()`. This can be done by printing data to console from within the generate.

Comment: It runs the lol message when Generate() is called, but I get no new elements.

Comment: Note that `Const` is a syntax error. It should be `const`. Please make sure that you post here is exactly the same as what you are actually using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}>
   {data.items.map(({id, url, title}) => (
      <MenuItem key={id}> 
        <Link to={url}> {title} </Link> 
      </MenuItem>
   )}
</Menu>
```

Or, if you want use the function, call it:

```
const Generate = items =>
  items.map(({id, url, title}) => (
     <MenuItem key={id}> 
        <Link to={url}> {title} </Link>
     </MenuItem>
  )
;
```

So:
`{Generate(data.items)}`
Pass parameter is a good idea because it makes Generate a pure function!

Comment: So, this did what I wanted it to do. Calling the function doesnt work, but writing it directly in does. Any idea why?

Comment: I think is because data need to be a parameter... and you don't need " { "

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use `.map()` function when you're mapping over a list of objects, and in your case, why don't you try something like this ?

```
Const Generate = () => {
  {data.items.map((e,i) => (
    <MenuItem key={i}> 
      <Link to={e.url}> {e.title} </Link> 
    </MenuItem>
   ))}

  }
```

This should be working for you.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have the right idea. The first thing that pops out to me is that `Generate` is a function, but you never call it. Instead you have `{Generate}` which evaluates the function object directly, not what it returns. Instead you probalby should have `{Generate()}`.

I suggest you debug your code more by adding more `console.log()` calls. Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for more tips on debuging your code.

Another problem I see is in the syntax for your `Generate()` function:

```
Const Generate = () => {
  {data.items.map(({id, url, title}) => (
     <MenuItem key={id}> 
      <Link to={url}> {title} </Link> 
     </MenuItem>
))
console.log('lol')}
}
```

In particular, I think you have some extra braces. The correct syntax should be something like this:

```
const Generate = () => {
  console.log('lol');
  return data.items.map(({id, url, title}) => (
     <MenuItem key={id}> 
      <Link to={url}> {title} </Link> 
     </MenuItem>
  ));
}
```

1. There is only one set of curly braces enclosing the body of the fat arrow function. The syntax here is `(<params>) => {<statements>}` where `<params>` is the list of parameters and `<statements>` is the list of statements to execute.
2. When using curly braces around the statements in a fat arrow function, you must include a `return` statement in order to return a result. This is necessary because of the `console.log()` statement. If there is only one statement, then the curly braces can be removed and the single statement doesn't need a return:

   ```
   const Generate = () =>
       data.items.map(({id, url, title}) => (
           <MenuItem key={id}>
               <Link to={url}> {title} </Link>
           </MenuItem>
   ));
   ```

Comment: My bad. As I have stated in the other answers, I had that previously, but removed it while debugging for some reason. the console log gets called, but nothing is rendered. When writing it directly into the flow as @Claudio suggested, it works. Im at a loss

Comment: @MariusZ I added some more suggestions to my answer. See if they help.